# Find the following composition of the relations given below: (Rosen 7 Ex 36 Chapter 9 if it helps someone)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Given R = Set of all real numbers, define the following relations:

R1 = {(a, b) ∈ R^2 | a > b}, the “greater than” relation,

R2 = {(a, b) ∈ R^2 | a ≥ b}, the “greater than or equal to”
relation,
R3 = {(a, b) ∈ R^2 | a < b}, the “less than” relation,

R4 = {(a, b) ∈ R^2 | a ≤ b}, the “less than or equal to”
relation,

R5 = {(a, b) ∈ R^2 | a = b}, the “equal to” relation,

R6 = {(a, b) ∈ R^2 | a != b}, the “unequal to” relation.

Find:

a) R1 ◦ R1 - 
My answer: R1

b) R1 ◦ R2. - 
My answer: R1

c) R1 ◦ R3. - 
My answer: R^2 because if a <= b and b > c, then both a and c might be arbitrary (doubt here)

d) R1 ◦ R4. - 
My answer: R^2 because if a < b and b > c, then both a and c might be arbitrary (doubt here)

e) R1 ◦ R5. - 
My answer: R1 because if a = b and b > c, then a > c which is R1.

f ) R1 ◦ R6. - 
My answer: R^2 because if a != b and b > c, then both a and c might be arbitrary (doubt here)

g) R2 ◦ R3. - 
My answer: R^2 because if a < b and b >= c, then both a and c might be arbitrary (doubt here)

h) R3 ◦ R3. - 
My answer: R3 because if a < b and b < c, then then a < c

Please correct me if I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clarifying the doubts:

- $R_1 \circ  R_3 = \mathbb R^2$ $$\text{Yes, you are right.}$$
- $R_1 \circ R_4 = \mathbb R^2$ $$\text{Yes, you are right.}$$
- $R_1 \circ R_6 = \mathbb R^2$ $$\text{Yes, you are right.}$$
- $R_2 \circ R_3= \mathbb R^2$ $$\text{Yes, you are right.}$$

And the others are also right. Well done!

Comment: Thank you! .. :)

Answer (score 0):

R2 ◦ R1
b) R2 ◦ R2

c) R3 ◦ R5

d) R4 ◦ R1

e) R5 ◦ R3

f) R3 ◦ R6

g) R4 ◦ R6

h) R6 ◦ R6.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).